# Alembic doesn't recognize False default value

Tags: python, database, postgresql, sqlalchemy, alembic

While maintaining a SQLAlchemy data model and utilizing alembic for version control, the following code change I made resulted in an empty revision:

```
some_column = Column(Boolean, nullable=False, default=False)
```

While previously it was:

```
some_column = Column(Boolean, nullable=False)
```

So adding a default value produces no changes in alembic, i.e. generates an empty revision. I tried other values offered by SQLAlchemy like `false()` and `expression.false()` instead of `False`, but the result is the same (empty alembic revision). Also tried `server_default` instead of `default`. The database in question is PostgreSQL.

By empty revision, of course I mean that alembic doesn't recognize any change being made in SQLAlchemy:

```
def upgrade():
    # ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
    pass
    # ### end Alembic commands ###


def downgrade():
    # ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
    pass
    # ### end Alembic commands ###
```

Appreciate any help in this regard.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*To do this automatically* you have to turn on a setting to detect server default changes.

In your `env.py`, for the `context.configure` calls (online and offline migrations, so in **2** places), add a `compare_server_default=True` kwarg.

It is probably safer to just put in the `alter_column` yourself as well as definitely use `server_default` because `default` is just for python-side setting of the default(which is ok but sounds like not what you want).

Quoted from https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/autogenerate.html#what-does-autogenerate-detect-and-what-does-it-not-detect

> Autogenerate can optionally detect:
>
> ...
>
> Change of server default. This will occur if you set the
> EnvironmentContext.configure.compare_server_default parameter to True,
> or to a custom callable function. This feature works well for simple
> cases but cannot always produce accurate results.
>
> ...

Answer (score 8):

Just pass `false()` in `server_default` kwarg in `Column`.

ref: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/sqlelement.html

```py
from sqlalchemy.sql import false

some_column = Column(Boolean, server_default=false(), nullable=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Next part of code demonstrates how to define default value for new Boolean field in the table

```
from alembic import op
import sqlalchemy as sa

def upgrade():
    with op.batch_alter_table("jobs", schema=None) as batch_op:
        batch_op.add_column(
            sa.Column(
                "is_deleted",
                sa.Boolean(),
                server_default=sa.false(),
            )
        )
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This doesnt seem to work if you say are trying to do a bulk COPY from one table to another, but excluding a boolean column.